# .NET 6.0 Blazor - MSAL ErrorCode: Client_Credentials_Required_In_Confidential_Client_Application

Tags: .net, .net-core, blazor, identityserver4, azure-ad-msal

I have a .NET Blazor application that I'm deploying to an IIS Server which integrates with Azure Active Directory.

I have performed the necessary App Registration, created the relevant configuration settings  (appsettings.json) and added the necessary re-direct Uris.

```
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "<redacted>",
    "TenantId": "consumers",
    "ClientId": "<redacted>",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "Secret": "<redacted>"
  },
  "MicrosoftGraph": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
    "Scopes": "user.read"
  },
```

In the program.cs, all the necessary calls to enable Identity Authentication are present:

```
var initialScopes = builder.Configuration["DownstreamApi:Scopes"]?.Split(' ') ?? builder.Configuration["MicrosoftGraph:Scopes"]?.Split(' ');

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
.AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

var configuration = builder.Configuration;

builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddMicrosoftAccount(microsoftOptions =>
{
    microsoftOptions.ClientId = configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"];
    microsoftOptions.ClientSecret = configuration["AzureAd:Secret"];
});
```

Running from my local machine, everything works perfectly as it should. (Good old WOMM!)
A user can sign in, having re-directed to the Microsoft Login Pages and gets authenticated correctly and the app functions as it should. (I can expose the service to the outside world and it works for others as well).

However after deploying to the server, on an IIS host, after the user authenticates with the Microsoft Login, the re-direct url is called (the default /signin-oidc) and an internal server error is thrown.

After adding some global error handling, I was able to extract the following error:

```
Error: System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
---> MSAL.NetCore.4.47.2.0.MsalClientException: ErrorCode: Client_Credentials_Required_In_Confidential_Client_Application Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalClientException: One client credential type required either: ClientSecret, Certificate, ClientAssertion or AppTokenProvider must be defined when creating a Confidential Client. Only specify one. See https://aka.ms/msal-net-client-credentials.
```

I'm a tad lost, and can only assume that the code I have works great for Kestrel and not for IIS and I need to be following a different flow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of reading around here:

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/MSAL.NET-or-Microsoft.Identity.Web

...and checking out various Visual Studio Templates specifically mentioned for my scenarios here:

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/web-app-template

... I discovered that the following fluent API calls weren't needed:

```
  .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
.AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

Adding these into the sample templates yielded the same error (out of idle curiosity), but it was clear from the above links that they weren't needed unless I was needing to refer to tokens in the project (which I don't).